# Create new columns for each ID

Tags: mysql

Say I have a table (~1M rows) looks like this:

```
ID        
1   
2   
3     
4     
5     
6     
.     
.     
.
```

I want to add Year and Month columns to it for full year of 2014 and 2015.
so the output becomes:

```
ID  Year  Month
 1  2014    1
 1  2014    2
 1  2014    3
 .    .     .
 .    .     .
 .    .     .
 1  2015    12
 2  2014    1
 2  2014    2
and so on so forth.
```

How can I do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to create a `cartesian product`.  Here's one option using `cross join`:

```
select t1.id, t2.yr, t3.mnth
from yourtable t1 
    cross join (select 2014 yr union all select 2015) t2 
    cross join (select 1 mnth union all select 2 union all select 3 union all
                select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all
                select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9 union all
                select 10 union all select 11 union all select 12) t3 
order by t1.id, t2.yr, t3.mnth
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6fa5f6e/4)

Comment: your solution works with minor modifications:
    select t1.id, t2.yr, t3.mnth
    from yourtable t1 
        cross join (select 2014 yr union all select 2015 yr) t2 
        cross join (select 1 mnth union all select 2 mnth 
           union all select 3 mnth union all select 4 mnth
           union all select 5 mnth union all select 6 mnth 
           union all select 7 mnth union all select 8 mnth
           union all select 9 mnth union all select 10 mnth
           union all select 11 mnth union all select 12 mnth) t3 
    order by t1.id, t2.yr, t3.mnth
Thanks!